# Can you set a default/current value for UIStepper object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uistepper

I tried to do something like this in the viewDidLoad method:

```
 self.myStepper.value = 10.0;
```

But it's not working. I've googled and googled and I can't find any answers to this. It seems so easy for a slider, but can you do it with a stepper as well?

Comment: Is this value between your steppers' minimumValue and maximumValue? the value method will clamp your value to one of the extremes, if it is not inside.

Comment: How do you accept an answer? I thought you just voted it up, because I've been doing that. Sorry, I'm kind of new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stepper values need to be within bounds of min and max, or like in the comments to your question they get pushed to either the min or max.  Always check Apple's Reference docs.
Reference:   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I simply forgot to init the steppers in the viewDidLoad method. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

We can set the Value for the Stepper using the Below Syntax,

[your_stepper_name setValue:your_stepper_value];

ex:

[stepper setValue:10];